# SSIS dynamic flat file connection to load daily file with date-time,minute,second timestamp

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, flat-file, dts

I have to load the daily csv file from a network location which has the date time stamp with minute and second when it gets exported from api and saved to a network location. 
I am trying to make my package dynamic so it does not change when the file name changes every other day. I have tried using an expression in the flat file manager connection properties but that not working either.

My file name looks like following:
DS_All_users_with_additional_fields_2018_12_11_10_00.csv

which i have tried to solve my using the following expression but things gets complicated if there is delay in the csv export and the minute and second changes in the file name:

@[User::DataLoadDir]+"DS_All_users_with_additional_fields_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))+"_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))+"_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)DAY( DATEADD( "dd", 0, getdate() ))+"_10_00.csv"

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop file enumerator and apply a filespec expression of:

`DS_All_users_with_additional_fields*.csv`

The `*` servers as a wild card and will pick up all files matching that string. You can work with this in order to make it flexible based off your needs. In this case, the job will scan for all files that are available in a specific folder that matches the above string. This can then be assigned to a variable, which you can use to dynamically set the connection string.

I don't think you can add the `*` into the connection string itself.

**Update**

To set a connection manager's connection string property, see the photo below. It is import to note that this solution will change the work flow. Your initial work flow was telling the connection manager what file to specifically look for. However, by implementing a foreach loop, the job is now searching for any and all files that are available in a specific folder path. Note: you will need to make sure that you include the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in the connection string variable (i.e., \\networkpath\filename.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how to create a connection string variable. My file is exported with the date time stamp with minute and second when it was extracted. How can i make the flat file connection dynamic enough to use it daily?

Answer (score 0):

Are the files that you need to import the only files in that directory with a name that starts with `DS_All_users_with_additional_fields_`?  If so, use a Script Task to find the most recent one and set the variable used in the connection string to this name.  The following example uses `LINQ` to look for files that begin with the name you listed, then sorts them by the date they were created on, and returns the name of the first one.  The `Name` property below will include the extension.  You can also get the complete file path by changing this to the `FullName` property, in which case you could just use this value for the variable used by the flat file connection string, as opposed to concatenating it with the `@[User::DataLoadDir]` variable.  This example does reference `System.IO` and `System.Linq` as specified below.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string filePath = Dts.Variables["User::DataLoadDir"].Value.ToString();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
FileInfo mostRecentFile = (from f in di.GetFiles().Where(x =>
                    x.Name.StartsWith("DS_All_users_with_additional_fields_"))
                      orderby f.CreationTime descending
                      select f).First();     

//The Name property below can be changed to FullName to get the complete file path
Dts.Variables["User::VariableHoldingFileName"].Value = mostRecentFile.Name;
```